# text file not opening ( linux python 2.7 )

Tags: python

i get this error when trying to open a text file:

```
 IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'text.txt'
```

it works fine in windows but in linux mint it wont open. and im pretty sure that there is a file called text.txt in the directory of my main.py file

this is the code :

```
file_ = open('text.txt', "r+")
load = pickle.load(file_)
print load
var = load

file_.close()
```

it wont open when i run it in visual studio code, but when running the file in the terminal everything is fine

Comment: Pretty sure? Cause that'd be my first guess.

Comment: check if the file is actually in your dir, also best practice is ./{{filename}}.{{extension}}

Comment: @VitaliyTerziev What do you mean by your "best practice"?

Comment: it's not mine..

Comment: "*there is a file called text.txt in the directory of my main.py file*" It doesn't matter where your .py file is; what matters is which directory it is run from (the current working directory), which could be anything.

Comment: @VitaliyTerziev You made the comment, so now it's yours. And I don't understand it. What are you talking about?

Comment: @melpomene, this type of communication is fruitless, have a nice weekend

Comment: Please post a screenie of your file browser with the .py  and the test.txt in it! Just to make sure they are in the same directory!

Comment: i was being sarcastic of course im sure there is a text.txt file in the same directory as the main.py file

Comment: Basically a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939018/c-program-cant-open-file.

Comment: The strange thing is that in debug mode it runs fine but when I right click and select run python file in terminal i get the error

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36509855/python-program-cant-open-txt-file.

Comment: When you right-click your CWD is probably some default place, like your home directory, rather than the directory where the py file is.

Answer (score 0):

Opening a file named 'text.txt' opens file 'text.txt' in current workfing directory. To see what your current working directory is, do this:

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

In order to open a file which is in the same directory as the 'py' file from which you are trying to access it, first find out which directory that is and then use an absolute path to the file:

```
import os

current_py_file_path = os.path.abspath(__file__)
current_py_directory_path = os.path.dirname(current_py_file_path)
path_of_the_txt_file = os.path.join(current_py_directory_path, 'text.txt')
```

Actually, that is too verbose, it was just to explain. This should be enough:

```
from os.path import join, dirname

path = join(dirname(__file__), 'text.txt')
```

BTW, when you open the file, this is the simplest and safest way to do it:

```
with open(path, "r+") as file_:
    load = pickle.load(file_)

# no need to call close() - it happens automatically
# when you leave the *with* block. And it happens
# no-matter-what (i.e. even if there is an exception).
```